# Programmatically request location updates permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

How do I programmatically request location updates permissions? 
I mean, I what to control, when does the native popup asking for "Your current location" pops

purpose:
I what to control that if there is no permissions, to present something and only then to ask for them (apple native popup). How to that?

Comment: When you first try to use location and iOS hasn't previously asked permission for your app.

Comment: You don't do anything to request permissions. The proper thing is to check the authorization status and make use of the location manager appropriately. iOS will show the dialog as needed.

Comment: I what to control if there is no permissions, I want to present something and only then to ask for them (apple native popup). How to that?

Comment: Read the docs for `CLLocationManager authorizationStatus` do some searching on its use. You'll find plenty of sample code showing how to use it properly.

Comment: @maddy, not sure if your last comment was very constructive

Comment: @Luda You can check the current permission with the `CLLocationManager authorizationStatus`. But you can't present the request permission dialog your self, since there is no API to do this. The first time you use `CLLocationManager` it will present the permission dialog. If you do not have permission you will have to present a dialog your self and ask the user to give you permission via the settings app. You can not open the settings nor can you set the permission your self.

Answer (score 0):

You don't control the "Apple native popup".

You know whether the desired services are available through CLLocationManager class methods (`locationServicesEnabled`, `authorizedStatus`, etc). If location services are switched off, you can just start using a location manager anyway (e.g. `startUpdatingLocation`) - that is your only way of getting the system dialog asking the user to switch them on. Be prepared for the possibility that the user won't do so.

Of course nothing prevents *you*, having detected that you have been denied authorization, from putting up your own alert requesting that the user switch to Settings and authorize you.

Comment: I want, to put some view, saying "I'm gonna request location" and then to actually request them. This is the design. This is what I have to do. How to do that?

Comment: Read what I said. If you want to put up an alert, put up an alert. But you yourself cannot request authorization. Only the system can request authorization, and the user can only grant it to the system (through the system alert, or through Settings), not to you.

Comment: this request is happening once the app wants to use location services. The question is what exactly triggers this popup?

Comment: And I think I answered that.